# Extract number and compare using Awk

Tags: awk

Given a file of lines of the following format, I want to print those lines who have a time greater than X seconds.

2015-08-03 00:43:01, time taken to run = 10 seconds

How can I use a single line of awk to achieve this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the number of seconds is always in the penultimate field, you could use something like this:

```
awk '$(NF-1) > 5' file
```

`NF` is the number of fields, so `$(NF-1)` gets the value of the second to last field. If the value is greater than 5, the line is printed.

To use a shell variable instead, you can do something like this:

```
m=5
awk -v max="$m" '$(NF-1) > max' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If your log format is fixed, you can do this. For example greater than 9.

```
awk '/time taken to run/ && $8>9' log.txt
```